# Does putting single quotation marks around numeric constants really protect from SQL injection in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

The manual seems to suggest that using quotes around numbers is sufficient to protect from SQL injection.

According to section [5.3.1. General Security Guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/security-guidelines.html) of the *MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual*:

> If an application generates a query such as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=234` when a user enters the value `234`, the user can enter the value `234 OR 1=1` to cause the application to generate the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=234 OR 1=1`. As a result, the server retrieves every row in the table. This exposes every row and causes excessive server load. The simplest way to protect from this type of attack is to use single quotation marks around the numeric constants: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234'`. If the user enters extra information, it all becomes part of the string. In a numeric context, MySQL automatically converts this string to a number and strips any trailing nonnumeric characters from it.

Does that mean that the user is protected if the user enters the value `234' OR 1=1 #` ? (i.e. to generate the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234' OR 1=1 #'`)

Comment: If that's the kind of stuff in the MySQL reference manual it makes sense that the MySQL.com site was broken into via SQL Injection.

Comment: @mrdenny - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/28/mysql_hack/

Comment: This is still in the MySQL 8 reference manual under section 6.1.7 Client Programming Security Guidelines: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/secure-client-programming.html 

Comment: It's an extra-bad idea because it then has to parse a string to a number, and not everywhere uses the same decimal separator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer, no.  The quoting trick is easily defeated by including your own closing quote and then a comment symbol to eliminate the final concatenated quote, precisely as in your example.

To protect yourself from SQL injection **you must use bind variables**.  Changing your example to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = :X` and then binding the user's input to X solves the problem instantly and completely.  It is impossible to over-emphasize how important this practice is!

Answer (score 3):

User just has to enter `234' OR 1=1 --` (with the trailing space) to break this.

Answer (score 2):

The excerpt provided above will not prevent SQL injections. Even with single quotes the input can be modified to manipulate the quotes. With quotes the query will be:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234', where the input is `234`

Now consider the injected input: `234'; select * from passwords;select * from table where id='234`. This will create a query block of:

**SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234'; select * from passwords;select * from table where id='234'**

Depending on the front end language used, in my case PHP, there are built in functions like `mysql_real_escape_string` that can be used to reduce SQL injections. The only comment I can say about the documentation (apart from @mrdenny's humorous one) is that without the quotes, there are more injection possible.

Comment: Have you had experience with this ??? HA HA, just kidding. +1 !!!

Comment: @Rolando So far so good, but I am still paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's not such a bad "guideline" if you are using some kind of `magic_quotes` mechanism (which is bypassable only if you are using `GBK / Big5` or familiar character set(s) at the backend DBMS). It should properly filter/preformat all occurrences of character `'` which can easily enter the SQL injection into that statement (e.g. with payload you've stated `234' OR 1=1 #`).

But, to be 100% safe you should definitely use ONLY "parameterized" SQL statements!